# Modify CRUD and add some business

Tags: jhipster

I'm starting with jhipster and i'm wondering how to add or modify a page for example here i only got the CRUD. There are CRUDs that I dont need and there are classes (for my business) that i need but I don't have. And how to combine the 2 ??

Question2 : I jhipster-uml jhipter.jh twice, so now the entities.xml in the changelog are all red ? why is that ? the app still run with no problem but the i don't know why is it like that ?

I'm wondering if you got it all :/ Sorry

Comment: Don't post several questions at once, create one post per question, pescielaly when second one hsould be tagged jhispter-uml as it seems as it is not very clear.

Comment: Your 1st question is not very clear too, jhipster is a app generator, once generated the code is yours, you can do what you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it.
You have to kill your process and run the program again. Then your able to run the app. I use two different methods, check which one is best for you. In the terminal type (If you are using mac os):

```
1) ps aux | grep tomcat 
(to get the PID which is the process ID for tomcat e.g. 
76134   0.0  0.0  2444056    780 s000  R+   11:42PM) and 76134 is the PID
1:1) kill -9 76134 (at the moment for my machine the PID was: 76134)
```

Or to kill the process at the port 8080:

```
2) kill `lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP | grep 8080 | tr -s " " "\n" | sed -n 2p`
```

Then run mvn on your termian.

Comment: Did you create your database manually or not? 
If not go to your database creator and create the database manually, and rung the command again.
And check you configuration for postgres if everything is correct.

Comment: And run: 
       mvn compile liquibase:diff
and
      mvn liquibase:clearCheckSums

Comment: So now that i've delete this line   <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20150811124815_changelog.xml" 
relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>  from master.xml, it's like everything goes right, no more red but No !! No entities in my database that've alredy create.